# Store configs in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Where should i store links to api's in react?

Comment: Both your examples should be part of API, not UI, therefore I don't see any connection with react. Such constants should be completely outside .jsx. If you have them inside your components, you should first learn how to split your app correctly into layers.

Comment: @Sulthan when you need a dynamic entry point to a server for ajax requests for example, you must provide it to the UI somehow.

Comment: @Sag1v To UI? No. React does not send ajax requests. React displays data and triggers actions. The actions then trigger the request. All request related code should be in normal "js" files, completely outside react components.

Comment: @Sulthan it realy depends on how you structure your app inst it? some people will use `redux-thunk` (i see it as part of react) for ajax requests, some will even fetch inside `componentDidMount`. nevertheless, you still need this info inside your js files (any js file) and you would like to keep it isolated from the global / window scope of course

Comment: @Sag1v A/ - a Javascript contant, imported to the files where it is needed (can be also generated during build) 2. Solution B/ A json file, read using $ajax at startup, saved to a JS constant, imported to fiels where it is needed.

Comment: @Sulthan A: If its dynamic it can't be generated during build. B: fetching a `json` file is nice when you know the `server-url` which is exactly what the OP asked! :)

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan i think i can understand it better now!

Comment: @Sag1v You don't need a server URL for a local file. Ajax can load even jsons that are packaged with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it via `data-attributes` on the `root` element.
If you think about it, you already targeting the `DOM` to get the root element for the App render. so before you render it, grab the `data-attribute` and store it's value.

```
<div id="app" data-server-url="myserver.com"></div>
const rootElement = document.getElementById('app');  
const serverUrl = rootElement.getAttribute('data-server-url');
// render your app as you normally doing...
// but now you can pass in the server-url as a prop
ReactDOM.render( <App serverUrl={serverUrl} />, rootElement)
```

Comment: Thanks Sag1v.
Isn't this way a little bit complicated when you have a lot of attributes?

Comment: i don't see how complicated it is. this way you are passing variables from the `DOM` while keeping them none global. if i need dynamic configurations from the server / API then all i need in the `DOM` is the entry point to the server, then i `fetch` the configuration data from the server and use it in my store inside react. it realy depends on your use case.